# Delphi pass static array as var in function parameter

Tags: delphi

I can't seem to find any information or understanding why the compiler throws error " E2029 'OF' expected but '[' found " when I try to use static array instead of dynamic.

I'm calling functions form a DLL file, so I'm having this code:

```
function RetrieveDSOData(whatchannels: uchar; var DSOCH1, DSOCH2: array of double; 
var LADATA: array of ushort; Nth_Sample: uchar): longint; 
stdcall; external 'E_l80.dll';
```

This compiles ok, but I have AV errors in DLL files, and since I suspect that the issue is the dynamic array does not get size specified, I wanted to throw it a static array.

But, if I write the above function with

```
DSOCH1, DSOCH2: array [0..31] of double;
```

I get the compiler error mentioned above.

Additional info:
 I have instructions on how to use this DLL written for C, and since I barely know it, I might be missing something else around these arrays:
This is the original function:

```
long RetrieveDSOData(unsigned char whatchannels, double *DSOCH1,
double *DSOCH2, unsigned short *LADATA, unsigned char Nth_Sample)
```

with explanations like this:

```
*DSOCHX: A pointer to an array of points from the DSO channels.
*LADATA: A pointer to an array of LA data
```

Any help would be appreciated.
(and please do not edit this question just for deleting this last sentence... makes no sense...)

Comment: Have you tried defining your own type and using that instead? `type TMyArray = array[0..31] of Double;`

Comment: You need to create a type alias `TMyArray = array[0..31] of double` and then use TMyArray.

Comment: True. The hint given (as well as in the answer) does get me through compiler, however now the app hangs at calling the function... :(
Do you happen to help me out on the second-part of the question...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a type, and use that type instead.

```
type
  TDSOArray = array[0..31] of double;

 function RetrieveDSOData(whatchannels: uchar; 
  var DSOCH1, DSOCH2: TDSOArray;
  var LADATA: array of ushort; 
  Nth_Sample: uchar): longint; stdcall; external 'E_l80.dll';
```

This will at least resolve the compiler errors. I'm a little confused by how you got from *an array of points from the DSO channels* to *array[0..31] of double*. I can't answer the rest of your question either, for the same reason - I don't know what *LA Data* is, so I don't know how you got to *array of ushort* for the  `LADATA` parameter.

Comment: On a side note, from what I've understood, the difference between "declare" and "define" is "define" is how you create a type, whereas "declare" is how you use that type as a variable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. Corrected. (*Define* seems more correct from a vocabulary standpoint. It is *defining* a type, not declaring you have one.)

Comment: Indeed, "define" is essentially a "definition" which when you put it in the context of a dictionary, for example, is explaining what something is.

Comment: Without the C header, you mean what? For that functions of the Dll..?

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, since it does solve the issues with the compiler and gets through it ok.
Though, the app now hangs when the function is called. Do you happen to  be able to help me out on the second part of the question...? :(

Comment: @JustMarc That calls for a new question.

Comment: @JustMarc: I've edited my answer; I can't interpret the types you provided later in the question, because you didn't include the information needed to do so, and I've no knowledge regarding the DLL you're trying to use. I've added specifics in my answer.

Comment: @ Ken white I've actually given all the informations about the dll that I have. That's in the documentation, nothing more (except for a few other functions).
I got ushort from 'unsigned short' in original function - I believe thats the same? The orig function is written in the question itself...  the 32 length array is just my assumption, since I know that there are max 32 data coming in at a time.   The orig function only says *LAData, but in the comment it is stated that array is returned, It is pretty tedious for me to figure this out.. But will post this as a new question in 5 minutes.

Comment: @JustMarc; What you posted here (which you said was *with explanations like this*) isn't clear. Somewhere there has to be information about what "*LADATA: A pointer to an array of LA data" means; I don't know what `LA` is, so I don't know what *an array of LA data* might be.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. :/    LA data is Logic analyzer data. The documentation about the DLL is here http://www.osciloskopy.com/resources/elab/ELAB_DLL_Documentation.pdf  - on page 6, very top, is the *LADATA "explained"...

I'm working on new questions right now...

Comment: You should include that link in your new question. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271201/translating-dll-call-functions-from-c-to-delphi

Comment: Almost certainly the arrays should be translated as pointers. And the open array `var LADATA: array of ushort;` can't match `unsigned short *LADATA` which is a plain by value `PWord`.

Comment: @David: The question here was related to the compiler error, and I answered it. There is a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271201/translating-dll-call-functions-from-c-to-delphi) related to translation of the functions themselves.

Comment: With interop questions it's always worth trying to fix every defect because they always come back.

Comment: @David: That's precisely why I asked the OP to create a separate question and ask about the translations there, where *every defect* could be addressed in a question about doing the translations. The primary question asked here was related to the compiler error, which was not necessarily related to interop - it would have happened if the function being called was Delphi code in the same unit..