# Getting the pointer data from function parameters (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, pointers

Continuing from the [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271201/translating-dll-call-functions-from-c-to-delphi/), being unfamiliar with pointers,

how to correctly call the function bellow, given the fact that the pointers in it are the data to be retrieved back, and how to actually get to that data after calling it?

```
function RetrieveDSOData(whatchannels: Byte; DSOCH1, DSOCH2: PDouble; LADATA: PWord; Nth_Sample: Byte): longint; cdecl; external 'E_l80.dll';
```

(Needed DSOCH1, DSOCH2 and LADATA  data...)
If it's in any help / important at all -> the documentation states that these are "pointers to an array".

In case this is a duplicate and I just didn't look by correct keywords, vote for closing this.

Thank you.

Edit: 
It is to be assumed the size can be received by the return of the function. Documentation states:
*Return: The number of samples in the DSO and LA arrays. This number may not
be (total blocks x 1024) as some samples at the beginning and end are thrown away for
various purposes.*
So, max size might be (1024 x 32samples x 2 (2x8 digital channels, 2 bytes?)) for LADATA array...

Comment: You need to know how long the arrays need to be

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, please see my edit. (I did not forget to add this info, just really didn't see the connection before..).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function with addresses of arrays, and it will fill these arrays. Example:

```
var
  DS1: array[0..31] of Double;

RetrieveDSOData(whatchannels, @DS[0], ...
```

Comment: Now if it is true that the function returns the array length, I believe there's no way to actually use it like `SetLength(DS1, RetrieveDSOData(whatchannels, @DS1[0].....` , especially since there would be 3 array length to be set, correct?  So, is it safe to have max sized static arrays, and then using function's return only to avoid looking at whole array each time, but rather just to where the data actually is..?

Comment: @JustMarc, declare DS1 et. al. as the maximum size and use the returning length to iterate the arrays. The SetLength would not have worked even for one array, since you have to allocate before the call. You could preallocate a maximum size and later set the actual size though if you prefer that.

Comment: @LURD thats what I thought. Thanks for confirmation. Still though, I just did that, but even using way above maximum possible size, the app still hangs when calling function the way MBo wrote the answer... :/

Comment: [to be deleted ]   - Debugging this shows me either AV error, or stack overflow if I use higher sized arrays. Is this worth asking new question?

Comment: @Just Marc Are you sure in `cdecl` calling convention?

Comment: @MBo  me not. I started by using what was familiar for me, stdcall, but Remy Lebeau  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271201/translating-dll-call-functions-from-c-to-delphi/   stated that it's probably safer to call cdecl instead.
Other functions (there are more, can be seen in the topic linked in the first sentence of the question), that work so far, work using both stdcall or cdecl.  This, however, doesn't with neither one...

Comment: @Just Marc You should carefully examine .h header file instead of trial and error method

Comment: @MBo, you didn't see other posts and comments -> There is only DLL file and rather poor documentation with C functions available...  No .h header file available :/   http://www.osciloskopy.com/resources/elab/ELAB_DLL_Documentation.pdf